# Spark non-deterministic results after repartition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is there some way to get deterministic results from dataframe repartition without sorting? In the below code, I get different results while doing the same operation.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand, randn
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.range(0, 100000)

# repartition dataframe to 5 partitions
df2 = df.repartition(5).persist()
df2.head(5)

Out[1]: [Row(id=5324), Row(id=5389), Row(id=6209), Row(id=7640), Row(id=8090)]

df2.unpersist()
df3 = df.repartition(5).persist()
df3.head(5)

Out[2]: [Row(id=1019), Row(id=652), Row(id=2287), Row(id=470), Row(id=1348)]
```

Spark Version - 2.4.5

Comment: Then it will be slower. Do orderby.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am looking for way to do it without sorting ( edited the post as well). Not sure if that is possible.

Comment: What Spark version are you using?

Comment: @mazaneicha I am using Spark 2.4.5

Answer (score 1):

This `non deterministic` behaviour is `expected`. Here's how...

1. `.repartition(num)` does a `round-robin` repartitioning when no columns are passed inside the function. This does not guarantee that a specific row will always be in a particular partition.
2. `.head(n)` returns first n rows of first partition of dataframe.

If you want an order, you need to use `orderBy` !

Answer (score 1):

According to this [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23207), repartitioning (by default) involves a local sort, and is fully deterministic. From the PR notes:

> In this PR, we propose ... performing a local sort before
> partitioning, after we make the input row ordering deterministic, the
> function from rows to partitions is fully deterministic too.
>
> The downside of the approach is that with extra local sort inserted,
> the performance of repartition() will go down, so we add a new config
> named `spark.sql.execution.sortBeforeRepartition` to control whether
> this patch is applied. The patch is default enabled to be
> safe-by-default, but user may choose to manually turn it off to avoid
> performance regression.

`head(n)` on the other hand is not (unless you apply `orderBy` which again repartitions dataset to one partition), but that isn't your concern right?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You are implying that "by default repartition is deterministic, while head(n) is non-deterministic". Then how do I figure out if something is being deterministic or not?   To give more context, I am using the repartitioned dataframe for model training and I get non-deterministic results from model prediction. However, when I don't repartition, I see the same results on different runs.

Comment: Apologies, in your case `df` is actually a `PythonRDD`, and I don't think JIRA that I mentioned is applicable since rdds follow different code path.

Comment: I.e. when I try your exact code using spark-shell, I'm getting the same (deterministic) output every time.